# How to split numbers in a file by lines, and assign the lines into new lists?

Tags: python, list, split, assign

How to split numbers in a file by lines, and assign the lines into new lists?

For example,
(numbers below are in a file)

```
2 56 39 4 
20 59 30 68 4
28 50 7 68 95 05 68
```

I want to make it

```
List1=[2, 56, 39, 4]
List2=[20, 59, 30, 68, 4]
List3=[28, 50, 7, 68, 95, 05, 68 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but you would do something similar to the following.

```py
list = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        list.append(line.split(" ")) # Split the space-delimited line into a list and add the list to our master list
```

Remember that `list` is now a list of lists of string elements representing the numbers on each line. You'll have to do type conversion when accessing these elements to get an actual number (use something like `int(list[list_index][number_index])`).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
result = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        result.append(map(int, line.strip().split()))

print(result)

Output:
[[2, 56, 39, 4], [20, 59, 30, 68, 4], [28, 50, 7, 68, 95, 5, 68]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you cared that the output will remains a string, so this is the easiest IMO:

```
with open('filename') as file:
    lines = [row.split() for row in f.read()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tested:

```
 with open('source.txt') as source:
     lines = [line.split() for line in source.readlines()]

Output:
[['2', '56', '39', '4'], ['20', '59', '30', '68', '4'], ['28', '50', '7', '68', '95', '05', '68']]
```

Comment: You can just do `lines = list(source)`

Comment: Why did you post [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43786023/3001761) again, ten months later?